# Elasticsearch: Intersection of array

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

Suppose my documents are like this

```
{
    "salary": {
        "max": 1572,
        "min": 682
    },
    "skills": [
        "Modula-3",
        "Max/MSP",
        "Arduino",
        "SPARK",
        "PL/SQL",
        "Processing",
        "Go",
        "Mathematica",
        "Modula-2",
        "IDL",
        "Heron",
        "Scheme"
    ],
    "company": "Merck",
    "experience": 0,
    "role": "Airport Security Screener",
    "cities": [
        "Ahmedabad",
        "Mangaluru",
        "Malegaon",
        "Bokaro Steel City",
        "Vadodara",
        "Kollam"
    ]
}
```

And I want to do a query in which I will provide a set of cities and will get the documents ordered according the cardinality of intersection. i.e suppose my set of cities is `["Ahmedabad", "Mangaluru"]`, then the cardinatlity of intersection of this query with the above document is 2. What should be my query?

Sample Response

```
{"_score": 4.0202227, "cities": ["Ahmedabad","Mangaluru","Visakhapatnam", "Vijayawada"]}
{"_score": 2.27, "cities": ["Ahmedabad","Visakhapatnam", "Vijayawada"]}
{"_score": 1.79, "cities": ["Mangalauru","Vijayawada", "delhi", "bombay"]}
```

I am using elasticsearch 5.2.2

Comment: Can you please provide a sample output?

Comment: @Richa updated with sample response

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help you?

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "cities": "Ahmedabad Mangaluru"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "cities": "Ahmedabad"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "cities": "Mangaluru"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the number of cities is not pre-defined. i.e I can have variable number of citiies in my query ?

Comment: You'd need to have a `"filter"` section for each city.

Comment: Can I have a query, where I don't need to have a filter section for each city ? why or why not ?

Comment: There might be one but if you tried my query already you would have seen the scoring of each document. Which is a simple count of matching cities. With other query the scoring might not be calculated like that, if there is such a query. With my query, you take full control of the scoring, with other query you need to rely on TF/IDF similarity scoring.

Comment: I would like to know the other one too and then choose the best one